# How do an array of pages can be loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Instead of request each *module* per line of code, I'm saving all the *modules'* string page in an array of *modules*,

```
var modules = ['mod1.html','mod2.html', ... , 'modN.html'];
```

and then pass to a function that suppose to put all the loaded *modules* into the *modules-panel div* at once.

```
function loadModules(modules, callback){
    var content = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++){
        $('#modules-panel').load(modules[i],function(){
            content.push($('#modules-panel').html());
        });
    }
    callback();
}
```

The issue is that only the last *module* appears where it should be.
The function should save the loaded *module* ( page ) into a stack repeatedly and then append all the *modules* in the page at once.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to get the HTML from these pages, it would be better to use `$.ajax` directly and then read the response from that instead of repetedly filling an extraneous element.

Also, your `callback()` logic is flawed. You need to call that once all the AJAX requests have completed. For that you can use `$.done`. Try this:

```
function loadModules(modules, callback){
    var content = [], requests = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++){
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: modules[i],
            success: function(html) {
                content.push($('#modules-panel').html());
            }
        }));
    }

    $.when.apply($, requests).done(callback);
}
```

It should be noted that this may not be the best pattern to use as it will mean your server may be deluged with requests. If you can, I would look in to using server-side includes instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is the place where the loadModules function is called:

```
var modules = ['loadfile.html', 'getFBinfo.html'];
loadModules(modules, function(data){
    var total = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        total += data[i];
    }
    $('#modules-panel').html(total);
});
```

Thanks for clarifying the issue! However the answer I've got was pretty simple!
I've taken the suggestion about *ajax*. The function became this:

```
function loadModules(modules, callback){
    var content = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++){
        $.ajax({
            url: modules[i],
            success: function(html) {
                content.push(html);
                if(content.length == modules.length){
                    callback(content);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As can be seen, I could return the callback function by comparing the length between what is passed to the function and the total possible/real length (the modules' length).

The problem now is to know what happens if the ajax request gets an error from the server.